# adams.freenode.net: *** Notice -- TS for #https changed from 1515925182 to 1272500695

Tags: irc

In IRC, if I join the `irc.freenode.net` channel's `https` room, I will get bellow information.

> adams.freenode.net: *** Notice -- TS for #https changed from 1515925182 to 1272500695

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Whats the meaning of it?

whats meaning of `TS`?

whats meaning of `changed from 1515925182 to 1272500695`?

I tried to join the `1272500695` room, but this not fit my thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"TS" is the channel's **creation timestamp**. It is usually shown in readable format when you join the channel, or when you use `/mode #chan`.

(The large number is a "Unix timestamp"; number of seconds since 1970-01-01. `1272500695` is 2010-04-29 00:24:55.)

In your situation, the message can be translated as:

> You have joined an empty channel. As the first person in it, you become a chanop.
>
> However, the channel is still owned (registered) by someone else. Services will now remove your chanop status.

#### Netsplits – the *original* purpose of timestamps

If the network [splits in two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netsplit) and the channel ends up with no people on one side, it automatically gets destroyed (as usually happens with empty channels). Any random person trying to join that channel would re-create it and automatically become a chanop (channel operator).

When the network gets re-linked, it needs to merge these two identically named channels from both sides. If their creation times are also identical, then they must be two halves of the same channel, and their user lists merged.

However, if the channel coming from one side has a *newer* timestamp, that means it was re-created; the chanop status of everyone from that side is considered illegitimate and automatically removed.

#### Services – the trick you are currently seeing

When you join and re-create a channel which had been previously registered with network services, the services software *fakes* a similar event in order to remove chanop status of everyone who joined. It is a faster and more reliable method than rushing to send regular `/mode -o` commands.

As an added bonus, this makes `/mode #chan` show the correct time of when the channel was *originally* created and registered.